# Turn triple window into one bow window, structural concern?

Tags: windows, framing, structural, construction

I have a very old window probably from the beginning of this house in 1970's. Now I want to replace this old aluminum window with a bow window. my question is there are two posts of the triple window. Are they  structural elements? Are they part of this triple window or the builder added them there to fit the aluminum double hungs?

The whole opening is as big as 120" X 56 3/4" I wonder the reason they put it there when they built this house. The window frame gave some support?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: You are correct without those the header would have been much wider. There are are new materials that may be able to do the job in the space you have if it is a perimeter footing.

Comment: I would expect that there are load bearing vertical elements between the larger central window and the two flanking windows. If this is the case, you can't simply cut away the elements between the central and flanking windows and replace the three windows with one large window. You would have to open up the wall all the way to the top pkate and replace the header with a longer and wider one. For a simple window replacement you would have to replace the three windows with three windows.

Comment: It doesn't help that the photos are tiny, but we don't have enough information to say. There may be studs in those dividers, but we can't tell whether they're load-bearing. You'll need to open things up or get someone on site. Good luck.

Comment: Voting to close as unanswerable.

Comment: An experienced carpenter could probably tell using a stud finder and other testing whether there is one large header over all three windows, and could tell how wide the header is. Depending on an evaluation of the header it is possible the even load bearing elements between the windows could be removed allowing the three windows to be replaced with one window without redoing the header.

Comment: I think the question is answerable to the extent that one can say to the OP that he cannot proceed to plan to replace the three windows with a single window without an expert evaluation of the framing around the windows. Would anyone have a recommendation on employing one of the the new visualization devices that interface with a smart phone?

Comment: thank you all. highly appreciate all comments. I hope I can design some low frequency imager for the construction industry to detect inside.

Comment: How wide is the central window? How wide are the side windows? What is the distance between the top of the window to the ceiling on the inside wall?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any window that offer support. The frames are typically too weak and cannot handle the weight. The common framing for a door or window has a king stud (full height), then a crippler stud (shortened to support the header), a header (similar to a beam) over the opening, and at the bottom of the opening is a single 2xx4 or 2x6 depending on the framing, and the supporting studs below it. See picture below and how it disperses the load.

[image: Rough opening framing]

So, between your 3 windows are a crippler, king, king, crippler and are there to support the structure. Hopefully, this answers your question.

FYI - What the diagram calls jack studs, I know as cripplers.

Comment: While it's true that those components may be present, we have no way of knowing whether they're load-bearing. That's the gist of the question.

Comment: thank you all for the comments.